# Firebase auth email/password signin not working in release mode with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

- WEB:-
  I am using firebase authentication for my flutter app with normal email/password sign-in. The login is working fine when I run the web app in debug mode. I am able to log in with my credentials but when I try to run it in release mode I am unable to log in with my email and password. It is not showing any error in the console, in the logs, or in any exception.

Android:- I am facing the same issue with android.

Added SHA-1 in console.

Signed the APP.

Configured the firebase for multiple time and checked SDK instructions.

Tried flutter clean.

```
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>

  firebase_auth: ^4.0.2
  firebase_core: ^2.1.0
```

Doctor summary:

```
\[√\] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows \[Version 10.0.19044.2364\], locale en-IN)

\[√\] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)

\[√\] Chrome - develop for the web

\[√\] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.2)

\[√\] Android Studio (version 4.1)

\[√\] VS Code (version 1.75.1)

\[√\] Connected device (3 available)

\[√\] HTTP Host Availability
```

Can anyone have faced the issue with flutter please help me to resolve this?

Comment: Have you add internet permission tag in android manifest file? ```<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />```

Comment: @Shanu we need to add it manually in app/src/main/res/androidmanifest.xml file.

Comment: @Shanu The issue for android has been fixed it's working like charm. Can you know how we can fix it for web.  Here it's working on debug but not in release mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try adding internet permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file in,
android/app/main/res/

add,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

inside `manfest` tag

Comment: Okay, I am facing the same issue with flutter web also. Have you ever faced the issue do you know anything.

Comment: Thanks. It's worked like charm. But I never used this tag before in my previous apps. There it was working properly. do you know why this happens?

Comment: There you can see another manifest file inside ```android/app/src/debug``` which runs while we debug an app (I think). Inside that manifest file there you can see internet permission tag is present, so while debugging there won't be any issue like you're facing when running release version.

Comment: Yes, it is there in the debug manifest file. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution for Flutter Web with Firebase Phone Auth**

If authentication is working on your Flutter Web app in debug mode, but doesn't work in release, it could be because your domain isn't authorised.

Visit the Authentication section in your Firebase project and add your domain to the "Authorized domains" section.

[image: Authorized domains configuration]

By default, "localhost" is an authorized domain, which allows you to use Firebase Auth in local debug deployments. However, your final hosting domain/IP address needs to be added for auth to work in release environments.